# k-means clustering using squared correlation in Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, cluster-analysis

I am trying to cluster data using the squared correlation coefficient since in the case of my data, -1 correlation is equivalent to 1 correlation (polarities do not matter).

How can this be done in Mathematica using the k-means algorithm?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClusteringComponents.html